# How to connect on-premises server to azure server?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to make a connection between on-premises server and azure server. I tried to ping the azure server IP from on-premises server but no connection was made (Note: I'm on a free-trial plan). I did some research and found out either VPN setup / ExpressRoute is required. My question is:

1. is it possible to make a connection in free-trial plan?
2. is there any way to make a hybrid connection without setting up VPN/ExpressRoute?

Comment: How did you connect to the Azure SQL server, with SSMS or T-SQL? What's the error message? we can't answer you without details.

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe it is, but it will cost you whatever the cheapest VPN costs (basic SKU).
2. [Azure Service Bus Relay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/relay-what-is-it) might be an option, depending on what you are after

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure you have set the [Azure SQL database firewall settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-server-level-firewall-rule), then the Azure SQL database will allow the connect from the On-premise SQL Server.

Azure SQL Server doesn't have the IP property, you must use the  fully qualified name to connect to the SQL Azure server, format like:

```
[servername].database.windows.net
```

You can get this On portal:

[image]

Hope this helps.